# What does the verb "pretender" mean?

Tags: traducción, verbos, false-friend

I have been under the impression that the verb *pretender* is a false friend and means "to intend, or to hope, or to expect". However in Google Translate it translates as "to pretend", and it even displays as a synonym to the verb *fingir* (*fingir* is the verb I always thought meant "to pretend").

My question:

What does the verb "pretender" mean?

Answer (score 5):

*Fingir* and *pretender* are not synonyms, but *pretender* **could** translate as *to pretend* but only in very limited circumstances.  *Pretend* has several meanings in English, and some of them could indeed be used for the meaning of *pretender* which the DLE defines thus:

> **pretender**
>   **1.** *tr.* Querer ser o conseguir algo.
>   **2.** *tr.* Hacer diligencias para conseguir algo.
>   **3.** *tr.* Dicho de una persona: Cortejar a otra.

So it can be *want to be or acquire something, to do what is necessary to get something,* or *to court someone*.  Let's compare with the OED's definitions for *to pretend*:

> **pretend**, *v.*
>   **†6.**
>   **a.** *intransitive. figurative.* To tend to an end or point in action, speech, etc. Also: to extend in time. *Obsolete.*
>   **b.** *intransitive.* To stretch or reach forward; to move or go forward; to direct one's course; to tend. Usually with to or for. *Obsolete.*
>   **†10. *transitive.* To intend, plan.**
>   **a.** With infinitive as object. *Obsolete.*
>   **b.** With clause as object. *Obsolete. rare.*
>   **c.** With simple object. *Obsolete.*
>   **12.**
>   **†a.** *intransitive.* To aspire; to have pretensions. Chiefly with to. *Obsolete.*
>   **b.** *transitive.* With infinitive as object. To aspire, presume; to venture; to try, attempt. *Now rare.*
>   **†c.** *intransitive.* To pay court to (a prospective spouse); to seek to be married to (a person). *Obsolete.*

Example sentences from the OED show sentences that would be translated with pretender:

- For to what fyn he wolde anon pretende, Þat knowe ich wel
  *Aquel fin que él **pretendería** pronto, el cual sé muy bien,*
- I wyll pretende To stey to my father.
  ***Pretenderé*** quedarme con mi padre.
- I find by experience that we cannot acquire that end which is pretended to by such addresses.
  *Noto por experience que no podemos conseguir aquel fin que **se pretenden** tales discursos.*
- We pretend, that this City, already famous for the Defeat of two of your Armadas, shall become far more so by the Disgrace of this your third.
  ***Pretendemos*** que esta ciudad, ya famosa por la derrota de dos de tus armadas, sea aún más famosa por la desgracia de esta tercera tuya.
- All oþir askiþ & sekiþ her ovne comodites; þou pretendist allone myn helþe & my profityng
  *Los demás piden y buscan sus propias comodidades; tú **pretendes** solo mi ayuda y mi beneficio*
- I am not such a fool as to pretend to you now I am poor, and you have got altogether above me.
  *No sé tan tanto para **pretenderte** ahora que soy pobre, y tienes todo por encima de mí.*
- It is difficult to forecast the feeling of Congress, and few pretend to guess the probable terms.
  *Es difícil predecir los sentimientos del Congreso, y pocos **pretenden** adivinar los términos probables.*
- Some pretende to hye estates & grete richesses, & other ben content with lytil estate.
  *Algunos **pretenden** altas condiciones y grandes riquezas, y otros están contentos con bajas condiciones.*
- That..Step..lays her under the Foot of the Man she pretends to.
  *Aquel...paso... le pone debajo del pie del hombre que ella **pretende**.*

However, as you'll no doubt notice, both between the definitions and the sheer spelling of the English, the use of *pretend* in this manner is rare today, almost completely usurped by its usage equivalent to *fingir*.  So while Google is technically correct in equating *pretend* and *pretender*, it's not very helpful, and it's flat out wrong to say that *finger* and *pretender* are synonymous.

Comment: (It took all my will power not to translate those into old Spanish haha)

Answer (score 1):

You've had a long answer from @guifa; I will give you a short answer.  In this case, Google Translate is wrong.  [Collins gives three definitions](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/pretender), and none of them is *pretend*.

In practice I use it in exactly two ways in everyday conversation:

1. This one is actually a related noun form: the old-fashioned way of saying *suitor* is

   **pretendiente**

   I used this a lot when reading fairy tales to my children when they were younger.
2. There is a question that asks about what someone is really trying to accomplish:

   **¿Qué pretendes hacer [con algo]?**

   This could be asked in a confrontational way or in an analytical way.